# Ffmpeg downloading slow?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Mine download speed is slow when I use ffmpeg to download a video. When I use other programs that use ffmpeg I am getting no problem but downloading on termux I am getting slow speed.

Comment: Mine speed is generally 12MiB/s but on ffmpeg Im getting 1.40MiB/s download speed?

Comment: Is this a question about ffmpeg or youtube-dl? How can we reproduce the isse?

Comment: ffmpeg but sometimes youtube-dl has slow speed too?